# Are there any services I can feed a REST API data into to utilize a better indexing?

Tags: api, rest, search, indexing, saas

I currently work on a project where the client is hooked to a specific API where they all their ads (cars.

However, the API im calling for searches etc of ads is just not good enough to find what me/consumers are asking for.

Is there any search services out there to have a look at?

I would like to be able to pass the result of the REST API to a service that index the data and where I can then query the data from that service and hopefully get better search results?

Thanks

Comment: elasticsearch comes to mind

Comment: Thanks, will check it out then